# In OAuth 2.0, what are the responisibilities of a pure Resource server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

We are building a "pure" resource server. By "pure" I mean that none of our data is user specific, and that is only going to be called my other programs with no user interaction (ie by cron job), and only by one user with no public access. Most of the tutorials on OAuth 2.0 are light on the details regarding the client credentials scenario, let alone one like this.

For an example of a "pure" resource server you can think of a REST webservice that controlls the lights (on or off) in an office building.

So, in OAuth 2.0 what are the responsibilities of such a resource server?

From my understanding it must:

1. Check for the presence of a bearer token.
2. If the token is present validate the token
3. Validating requires

   1. either requesting the authorization server behind the scenes to validate it, or if using JWT :
   2. unpacking the token
   3. (if present) checking the signature/MAC matches
   4. (if present) that the resource is listed in the audience
   5. (if present) checking that the token has not expired
4. allowing the call the call if the token was valid, otherwise respond with a 403 and a message

So, I have three questions.

1. is the above correct?
2. is there any point in returning a 302 redirect when you know all clients will not be browsers?

Comment: I think your assumptions are correct. However, you described a very specialized scenario. What's the point of using OAuth2 here? I see no advantages that worth the additional complexity.

Comment: @ZólyomiIstván A blanket policy that requires all connections to be secured using OAuth 2.0 that is enforced by checklist wielding non-technical managers.

Comment: well, you got me, that's the all-winning ultimate reasoning. ;-)